# How do i populate the array object data into angular table

Tags: angular

I have an array object. I need to populate the data into angular table. I tried something but its not working properly.

This is the sample object that I need to populate in angular table

```json
[
  {
    "paramter": "BasisFunction1Value",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BasisFunction2Value",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasMatchImpedanceMagnitude",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasMatchImpedancePhase",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasMatchSeriesCapPosition_AI",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasMatchShuntCapPosition_AI",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasRFGenForwardPower_AI",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasRFGenReflectedPower_AI",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasRFTotalRFOnTime",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "paramter": "BiasRFVoltageProbeMonitor_AI",
    "chamberCountDTOList": [
      {
        "chamberName": "A1",
        "rate": 1
      },
      {
        "chamberName": "A2",
        "rate": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my code.

**table.html**

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>    
        <th *ngFor="let _paramInfoHeader of paramInfoHeader" class="verticalTableHeader">{{_paramInfoHeader}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>             
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
this.paramInfoHeader = [];
let _paraminfo = this.paramInfoViewData[0]['chamberCountDTOList'];
Object.keys(_paraminfo).map( data =>{
    this.paramInfoHeader.push(_paraminfo[data]['chamberName'])
});
```

I set the header but I don't know how to get the parameter and rate value in td.
Kindly check below image for reference.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5AMx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can go like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of paramInfoViewData">
      <td>{{data.paramter}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let chamberName of getChamberCountDTOListByParamter(data.paramter)">
        {{chamberName.rate}}
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the component:

```
getChamberCountDTOListByParamter(paramter: string): any[] {
    return this.paramInfoViewData.find((parm) => parm.paramter === paramter).chamberCountDTOList;
 }
```

Basically, you will find each chamberCountDTOList filtering by paramter

The result is here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either one of below

```
for(let i=0;i<this.r.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<this.r[i]['chamberCountDTOList'].length;j++){
    this.r[i][this.r[i]['chamberCountDTOList'][j]['chamberName']]=this.r[i]['chamberCountDTOList'][j]['rate'];
  }
}
```

(or)

```
this.r.forEach((item) => {
  item['chamberCountDTOList'].forEach((child) => item[child['chamberName']] = child['rate']);
  delete item['chamberCountDTOList'];
})
```